# React calculated field with state and props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following function in React, which depends on state and input properties(functions `getTotalQuantityRemaining`, `getTotalQuantityPending`).

How would I use calculated field instead of callback?

```
export interface MStatusProps {index: number; groupMed: GroupMed;}

const MStatus: React.FC<MStatusProps> = ({index,groupMed,
}: MStatusProps) => {
    const priceOptionsState = useSelector((state: ApplicationState) => state.mstate.priceOptions);
    const refillsRemaining = (): number | null => {
        if (!priceOptionsState.loading && priceOptionsState.errors.length === 0) {
            const daysSupply = priceOptionsState.data?.[id]?.daysSupply;
            if (daysSupply) {
                //getTotalQuantityRemaining,getTotalQuantityPending functions depend on groupMed
                return (getTotalQuantityRemaining() + getTotalQuantityPending()) / daysSupply;
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    };
    getTotalQuantityRemaining(): number {
        return groupMed.totalQuantityRemaining;
    };
    getTotalQuantityPending(): number {
        return groupMed.getTotalQuantityPending;
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi, please provide more detail about what you need.

Comment: I have received a `Is there a reason this is a callback instead of just a calculated value?` code review comment and I was wondering how would I change the function to use a calculated value instead of the existing function.

Comment: where did getTotalQuantityRemaining and getTotalQuantityPending come from ? i mean what is the functionality  of those functions

Comment: getTotalQuantityRemaining,getTotalQuantityPending functions depend on groupMed prop. I have updated the question.

Comment: hmm let me write down my answer for you

Comment: I am assuming what was meant was to use the `useMemo` hook to calculate the `refillsremaining`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the functions for static values there is no need for those functions, if you want to name those values for more understanding you can do something like this

```
export interface MStatusProps {index: number; groupMed: GroupMed;}

const MedicationStatus: React.FC<MStatusProps> = ({index,groupMed,
}: MStatusProps) => {
    const priceOptionsState = useSelector((state: ApplicationState) => state.mstate.priceOptions);
    // no need to define any functions to get the value
      const totalQuantityRemaining = groupMed.totalQuantityRemaining;
  const totalQuantityPending = groupMed.getTotalQuantityPending;
  const daysSupply = priceOptionsState.data?.[id]?.daysSupply; // i did'not see where the id comes from
  const refillsRemaining = (totalQuantityRemaining + totalQuantityPending) / daysSupply
```

Comment: The code review comment was about changing the refillsRemaining function to be a calculated field, when there is a dependency on state and props. This answer does not address that, does it?

Comment: i will edit the code

Comment: you should not use the function at all for this purpose

Comment: If there was any change in the props the component will re-render